# C# file download returns corrupted file - TransmitFile

Tags: c#, file, download, response.transmitfile

On our server we are hosting 10+ websites under the same domain using virtual directory. Now, among them file download function is working in all websites except 2. I have checked everything with the following function but still it's not working.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(strFileName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileDirectory + @"\" + fileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Note that I have also tried to set code for Content-Length, clear response cache but nothing worked. In fact, I have also compared request header of working and non-working website page, but they were also same. Note that the file download works when I use the same code in ashx page! I am 99.99% sure that this must a problem with something other than coding as I didn't find any issue with other websites.

If someone can focus on this than it would be greatly appreciated! Otherwise I would have no choice to apply alternative solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't said what actually goes wrong... "corrupted file" could mean anything.

Comment: Oh, my bad. After uploading file when I download it, downloaded file is not being opened. That's the issue.

Comment: What diagnostics have you performed on the differences between the original file and the corrupt one? Are they the same size? Any pattern to the differences? Are you sure you don't just have a corrupt file on the server?

Comment: Yes, initially I got file size difference while download but when I used Content-Length then also it didn't work. I have checked the request headers of both working and non-working website page from where I was downloading file using fiddler. I don't know other techniques. If you have any better idea, please let me know.

Comment: Got it!! Finally I solved the problem. I had implemented Compression module long time before in project but didn't realized I have to check for text/xml ContentType of request. As soon as I removed it everything started working.